# What type of Intent object required Query tag for package visibility in API 30 in Android?

Tags: android

I have a question regarding package visibility in Android 11. I read the oficial docs and also checked stack overflow question-answer. But I've few doubts. Please check the code below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.test">

<application
.....>

     <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="open"
                    android:scheme=“xxx” />
        
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        
             
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        
                <data
                    android:host="www.xxx.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
              
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
    <activity
                android:name=".ABCActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

 </application>
</manifest>
```

**Doubt:**

1. I tried and understood that `<query>` tag suggestion is coming only outside of `<application>` tag. Am I right?
2. If you see my code like this `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` written inside particular TestActivity. Now If I'll move intent filter code outside of application tag, then how Android will understand that for which activity browsable is required?
3. There are multiple intent filter with BROWSABLE, so I need to declare query tag multiple times?
4. I saw that people uses intent tag inside query tag, and no one is using intent-filter. So is that fine?
5. Can I do one last request? Can someone please correct my code and post it in answer? I already reduced and added only required code according to my questions. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

*Usage 1:*

```
upiIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    val pm: PackageManager = packageManager
                val app: MutableList<ResolveInfo>? = pm.queryIntentActivities(upiIntent!!, 0)
```

*Usage 2:*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
    private List<ResolveInfo> sharingAppList = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager pManager = context.getPackageManager();
            sharingAppList = pManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

*Usage 3:*

```
mVersionName.setText(getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
```

Comment: The code in your question has nothing to do with package visibility. The package visibility rules are for *your* app seeing activities of *other apps*, for methods on `PackageManager` and related code. There is nothing that your app needs to change to allow other apps to see your own activities. So, 1) correct; 2) you do not move anything; 3) you do not do this; 4) `<intent-filter>` and `<query>` have different roles; 5) your code is fine for accepting inbound requests from other apps. We cannot correct your code for *outbound* requests from your app, because for all we know you never do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the detailed answer. So basically I got doubt from here: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#check-browser-available

Comment: @CommonsWare Also please check edited code

Comment: Your edited code still has nothing to do with package visibility. Where and how are you using `PackageManager` in your code, where package visibility becomes important? For example, the link that you provided refers to using `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`.

Comment: Yes, many places I'm using Android share functionality as well as queryIntentActivities for UPI payment purpose.

Comment: OK, so you need to identify the key elements of the `Intent` objects that you are using with `PackageManager` and set up the `<queries>` element based on those. It has nothing at all to do with the `<activity>` elements in your manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay so I searched "queryintentactivities" in my entire project and 2 usages are there. I edited in question. Can you please check?

Comment: As I wrote, you need to identify the key elements of the `Intent` objects that you are using with `PackageManager` and set up the `<queries>` element based on those. If you are confused about how to do this, I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where your [mvce] shows how you are creating the `Intent` objects that you are passing to `queryIntentActivities()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please check edited question

Comment: You need to set up a `<queries>` element with two `<intent>` child elements, one for `ACTION_VIEW` and one for `ACTION_SEND` with a MIME type of `text/plain`. See https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you post an answer with my manifest code then? I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest code in your question seems wrong, insofar as `upiIntent` needs more than an action string.

But, ignoring that, you would need a `<queries>` element like:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

The first `<intent>` matches an `ACTION_VIEW` with no content; the second matches an `ACTION_SEND` with a MIME type of `text/plain`.

Comment: I edited my code, can you please merge your code with my manifest code and paste entire manifest file in answer? I'm just confuse that where and how you're pasting this query code

Comment: @SychiSingh: You put `<queries>` as a child of the `<manifest>` element. [Here is a manifest that illustrates this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/blob/master/EmbedClient/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: But in that action.SEND - I'm using this: mimeType="image/*"  and you're saying text/plain

Comment: @SychiSingh: The Java code in your question is `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null); intent.setType("text/plain");`. That is `text/plain`.

Comment: Ok got your point. I was asking but I was confused because image is mentioned in my manifest, but yea you said that there is no relation what we declare in manifest. If we use query intent based on that we need to define.  Thanks. Also 2 last thing before closing and accepting your question. 1st. I edited my question and added usage about getpackage info,  Please tell me anything I need to do or not. And 2 point: I tried before adding query tag in my Android 11 device still I’m able to do UPI payment, even my target sdk is also 30. How is it possible?

Comment: @SychiSingh: "Please tell me anything I need to do or not" -- there should be no limits for you getting information about your own app, if `getPackageName()` is the standard `Context` one. "How is it possible?" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: A special thanks to you @CommonsWare for constantly helping me. You've cleared my all doubts. I appreciate that. PS: I upvoted and accepted your answer. Thanks once again.